# Spring MVC @getMapping headers, set value from application properties

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, header, application.properties, get-mapping

I want to set value from application properties for @getMapping headers.
I was trying this

```
@GetMapping(path = "/test/classify/{id}",
        headers = "${partners.api-key}")
```

But it doesn't work.
Is it possible to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

hi I think you should use @Value to get property and HttpServletResponse to set the header like this:

```
@Value("${partners.api-key}")
private String apiKey;

@GetMapping(path = "/test/classify/{id}")
public Object get(HttpServletResponse response){
    .....
    response.addHeader("api-key", apiKey);
    return object;
}
```

Comment: That is not the same as `@GetMapping(..., headers = "...")` because the annotation only maps requests that contain the specified header, see [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers--).